# angular-google-maps vs. angular-ui / ui-map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-ui

I'm new to angularJS and like to build an simple application, where an google map is displayed in order to load long/lat coordinates to display them in form of markers insight the map.
For me it looks like, there are two main google-map extensions  for angluarJS:

https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps

and

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map

Which one would you recommend to use? Are there any main differences? Which one could be more "official" (to get longer support, etc...)?

Comment: Your question is likely to end up being closed because _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: Okay.. this is a pity, because stackoverflow is a great platform to share experiences, best practices and ideas who to solve a problem. I don't know an equal platform with such an high grade of 
specialized and experienced colleagues. But ,by reading that (see accepted Answer): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147641/how-to-ask-a-recommended-design-tool-for-the-job-question-correctly-and-whe?rq=1 this kind of questions is okay, I only have to rewrite the question a bit. Isn't it something like nitpicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question and if the case, that someone hast the same dissension, here the way I go:
I decided to take https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps because here I get an working example at the shortest time and it looks like, there is an active support with an short interval of updates and patches.

Comment: Where are you getting "active support" for AGM coding problems. I'm not finding or getting it. Thx.

Comment: I found helpful and fast support by opening an issue on AGM at github.

Answer (score 6):

At this moment, I'd suggest using https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps (AGM). It is more advanced and mature than [ui-map](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map). AGM has several abstraction layers for markers, polygons, etc. and the bootstrapping process is more clean. I personally don't like Ui-Map's bootstrapping method. You have to define a global callback which is to be called after the google maps api is loaded.

- AGM has a bigger community.
- On the contrary UI-Map is less than 4KB while AGM is more than 100KB. So, UI-Map is a better solution if you are looking for something light weight (especially if the map is just a part of a bigger application).

Comment: can you suggest the best forum to get help solving problems with AGM. Their Google+ site has lots of questions, but few answers. I posted a problem to the Google Groups Angular forum and have no responses, or even views, after 2 days. Is Stackoverflow best? or are there other good forums to get help with AGM code?

Comment: I found helpful and fast support by opening an issue on AGM at github.

Comment: If there's a possible issue or a bug, report it on github. If you're stuck in something, I think [their community](https://plus.google.com/communities/101653511105172739950?utm_source=websiten&utm_medium=link) or Stackoverflow are the best options.

Comment: This is helpful.  Couldn't get the other one working on fiddles or Koding.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me they are both immature compare to other non-angular google map API abstractions. I've worked with several and the best I've seen so far is http://leafletjs.com/ but it's *not google maps* it's open street maps. 
https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive